# What's the name of this font in this image?

Tags: photoshop

Hi,

What's the name of this font? How to make this kinda font effects in photoshop? Thanks.

http://sstatic.net/photo/img/logo.png

Comment: Actually this probably was a question for the Meta section: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so could someone please move it there...

Answer (score 6):

It's this font:

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/artill-typs/sketch-block/

No additional photoshop effect applied(besides color).

Comment: Well, that's an answer from someone who knows!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident the font is [Kulturista Bold](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/suitcase/kulturista/bold/). The effect in Photoshop could be a mix Chalk & Charcoal, Colored Pencil, Angled Stroke, or just Texturizer with a specific pencil texture. Not easy to tell.

Comment: I agree that it looks very much like Kulturista Bold, but I don't think it's this typeface: the "o" is rounder than KB's, and the descender of the "g" is curlier on KB. Also the top of the "t" looks different.

Comment: You are right about the 'o', but if you type 'Photography' in the sample box following the font link, I think the 'g' and 't' are the same. The 'o' could have been compressed manually?